# Trend Estimation by Differencing

Tags: time-series, stationary-processes

Consider a linear trend model, i.e.
$$X_t = \mu + \beta\cdot t + N_t$$
We then have
$$(\nabla X)_t = (1 - B)X_t = \beta + (1 - B)N_t$$
where $\nabla$ is the lag-1 difference operator and $B$ is the backshift operator. In the lecture notes at my university, it is stated that

> If differenced noise $(1 - B)N_t$ is stationary, we can estimate slope $\beta$ from data as the mean of the differenced time-series $\nabla X$.

Note that
$$\mathbb{E}[(\nabla X)_t] = \mathbb{E}[(1 - B)X_t] = \beta + \mathbb{E}[(1 - B)N_t]$$
I am wondering, if $\mathbb{E}[(\nabla X)_t]$ is still a good estimate of $\beta$ even if $\mathbb{E}[(1 - B)N_t]\neq 0$?

Also, why do we assume that $(1 - B)N_t$ is stationary in the quoted statement above? Are there any useful implications of this assumptions?

---

**Example**

Consider the time series
\begin{equation}
X_t = \mu + \beta\cdot t + N_t
\end{equation}
where $\mu,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and the noise is modeled as Gaussian random walk with drift, that is,
\begin{equation}
N_t - N_{t-1}\sim\mathcal{N}(\kappa,\sigma^2)
\end{equation}
for some $\kappa\neq 0$ and $\sigma^2 > 0$. In this case, we obtain
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[(\nabla X)_t] &= \mathbb{E}[(1 - B)X_t]\\
&= \beta + \mathbb{E}[(1 - B)N_t]\\
&= \beta + \kappa
\end{align}
If $\kappa$ is large in magnitude, then $\mathbb{E}[(\nabla X)_t]$ is not a particularly good estimate of $\beta$.

Comment: Hi: google for "trend stationarity versus difference stationarity". in your case, your model is trend stationary so you can estimate the slope ( estimate $\beta$) and then remove that term from the model by subtracting it from the other side. The resulting data should be stationary. Difference stationary is a different type of stationarity that doesn't apply in your case.

Comment: Hi @markleeds, thanks for your reply. What is still unclear to me is how we can estimate the slope $\beta$ from $\mathbb{E}[\nabla X]$ in the case where $\mathbb{E}[(1-B)N_t]\neq 0$.

Comment: what is $N_t$. Is that just different notation for the standard error term $\epsilon_t$ ?

Comment: Take a  look at "simplest example: stationarity around a linear trend, at this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trend-stationary_process. Note that, if the mean of the $N_t$ is not zero ( like it is in their example), then, when you test for stationarity, you have to test that the mean of $N_t$ is equal to its non-zero mean rather than zero. Other than that, the procedure is the same. Note that testing for stationarity is usually done using a DF test or by looking at the plot of the series in a graph.

Comment: @markleeds $N_t$ denotes an arbitrary noise process. The Wikipedia article assumes that $N_t$ is stationary, then $\mathbb{E}[(1-B)N_t] = 0$ which makes sense. However, if we assume that $(1-B)N_t$ is stationary, we cannot conclude that $\mathbb{E}[(1-B)N_t] = 0$.

Comment: that's right. so, when you create the residuals, instead of testing them for zero mean, you'd have to test them for a constant mean. I don't know if you're familiar with the Dickey Fuller  test but it can be used to test for a non-zero ( but constant ) mean.  Hamilton's "Time Series Analysis" has a nice chapter on the DF test where it considers the various cases.

Comment: Hi @markleeds, thanks again for your help. Is it correct to assume that the term "residuals" refers to $(1-B)N_t$? Also, if $\mathbb{E}[(1-B)N_t]\neq 0$, then we have to adjust our estimate of $\beta$, i.e., we cannot use $\mathbb{E}[(\nabla X)_t]$ as our estimate of $\beta$? I have added an example in my initial post, which illustrates the issue.

Comment: Hi:  When you have a trend stationary series, differencing is not the way to go to get the estimate of $\beta$. Plus,  in your case, ( given your example ) what complicates things even more is that you've got an non-stationary error term. So, I'm not sure what the best way to estimate $\beta$ is ( I'll check it out if I have time ) but, even if the residual ($N_t$) had an expected value of zero, you wouldn't estimate $\beta$ by differencing. You do that when you have a difference stationary process. Trend stationarity ( what you have there )  is a different animal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want $\mathbb{E}[\nabla X]$ to be a good estimator for the slope, then yes, the closer $\mathbb{E}[(1-B)N_t]$ is to $0$, the better the estimation will be, but that's slightly besides the point.

Say that, as you wrote, $\mathbb{E}[(1-B)N_t] = \kappa$, where $\kappa$ is known. Then we simply take $\mathbb{E}[\nabla X] - \kappa$ to be the estimator. On the other hand, if $\kappa$ is not known, $\mathbb{E}[\nabla X]$ will be an unreliable estimator, because we don't know how to split it into $\beta$ and $\kappa$. It's not like we are emotionally attached to this particular estimator, it's just that it is the key concept for solving such problems, and simple modifications to the problem that can be solved very easily are not mentioned, because there are too many modifications to mention.

Hope this provided a useful change in perspective.

Comment: Hi Carl, thanks for the helpful answer. Your perspective did indeed answer my question. It seems that I should not take the quoted statement literally. It is sometimes difficult for me to decide whether a given statement should be analyzed rigorously or qualitatively...